# C++ array subscription

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm having a problem getting the desired behaviour with array subscription and assignment.

Is there any way to determine whether assignment is used with array subscription?

**EDIT**
My question probably should have been, can I map [] to a getter, and []= to a setter

```
// Expect this to return a reference to the value if the key exists, 
// or throw an exception if not
myMap["Key"];

// Expect this to always return a reference to the value
// so the value can be populated
myMap["Key"] = "Value";

// The method being used
template <typename K, typename V>
V& MyMap<K, V>::operator[](const K &key)
{
    if(this->keyExists(key))
    {
        return this->find(key);
    }
    else
    {
        // At this point I'd like to throw an exception if
        // assignment is not being used
        this->insert(key, NULL);
        return this->pairs[this->itemsStored].val;
    }
```

};

Comment: So is this an array or a `std::map`?

Comment: What is the type of `myMap`?

Comment: It's my own map implementation, can't use std::map unfortunately

Comment: `std::map` doesn't distinguish, so I would not bother trying to do it yourself. You could jump through flaming hoops by returning a temporary object that throws an exception on destruction if its `operator =` hasn't been called (though you're not supposed to throw from destructors) and has an implicit type conversion to the value type... but I'd rather just accept that C++ doesn't distinguish between reads and writes with `operator[]`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman : you could make a `const` and non-`const` version of `operator[]` though ... but that'll probably be more hassle than it's worth.

Comment: Why throw an execption at all? Just default construct the object. Having multiple different behaviours in one method is not good style IMO. If you really want an exception than throw it always if the key does not exist, use your insert method then to populate.

Comment: `std::map` default constructs an object if it doesn't exist at the key location.  If the goal is to mimic the standard map, you should also use that approach.  You should also have a const and non-const version.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to determine whether assignment is used with array
>   subscription?

Simply, no.

When you do:

```
myMap["Key"] = "Value";
```

You're calling two member functions:  first, `map::operator[]` and then -- on a totally different class -- `key::operator=`.  When you simply do `myMap["Key"]` without the assignment nothing has changed with regards to how you interface with the map.  The only difference is what you do *next*.

You could, I suppose, find some technical hack (like providing a `const` and non-`const` version that do different things) which will provide the behavior you are trying to achieve -- but it will be at the cost of poor design.  Since you have perscribed within the non-const version that a missing key will be added, subsequently throwing in the non-`const` version is a major difference.  This will be a nightmare to maintain.  You will have very strange bugs arise when one version is actually being called when you expected the other to be called.  People using your code will be confused and curse your name.  *Don't do it.*

Instead, I suggest you're barking up the entirely wrong tree to begin with.  Instead of trying to use `operator[] const` to determine the existence of a key, why not simply provide a member function that does simply that?

You can, if you wish, have this function `throw` if the key doesn't exist or simply return a `bool`.

Comment: Actually, what he's trying to do is fairly simple.  That's what proxies are for.

Answer (score 0):

***DISCLAIMER** : what follows is bad practice, and I do not recommend actually using this. It's merely here to show that what the OP wants is technically possible, even though it's a really bad idea (for reasons I'll go into further).*

### The bad idea

If you don't mind a bit of hassle, you can have a `const` and a non-`const` version of `operator[]` that behave differently. The `const` version would throw an exception when accessing a non-existent item, while the non-`const` version would default-construct a new item in that case.

As a proof of concept :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

class Map {
    public :
        int value;

        Map() { value = 42; }

        const int& operator[](const size_t& pos) const { if (pos == 0) return value; else throw std::runtime_error("oops"); }
        int& operator[](const size_t& pos) { return value; }
};

void showValue(const Map& myMap, size_t pos) {
    try {
        std::cout << "myMap[" << pos << "] = " << myMap[pos] << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error e) {
        std::cout << "exception when accessing myMap[" << pos << "] : " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    Map myMap;
    showValue(myMap, 0);
    showValue(myMap, 1);
    myMap[0] = 5;
    showValue(myMap, 0);
    myMap[1] = 10;
    showValue(myMap, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

would print :

```
myMap[0] = 42
exception when accessing myMap[1] : oops
myMap[0] = 5
myMap[0] = 10
```

But the hassle I mentioned earlier, is to make sure the `const` version is used whenever the result won't be modified (in the example above, that's done by using a `const` reference).

### Why it's bad

As mentioned at the beginning (and as pointed out by John Dibling in comments), this approach is not recommended. The problem is that :

- it's difficult to know which version of `operator[]` will be called (in those cases where both can be called)
- the two versions of `operator[]` behave differently (one throws an exception while the other would add a new item when called with the same argument)

Combine these two observations, and you get close to unpredictable behaviour, which will hurt you when you least expect it (trust me). And worse, it might be difficult to track down and fix such issues when they occur.

As a rule of thumb, the `const` and non-`const` versions of any member function should not differ in their core functionality. Violate that rule, and you invite the wrath of whoever has to maintain the code (and that probably includes your future self).

### Any alternatives ?

So, don't do this. Instead, just either do it the same way `std::map` does (or better yet, just use `std::map`), or have a `contains` function you can call to check if an item exists.

Comment: Having `const` and non-`const` versions of the same function that have *substantially* different behavior is a terrible design.

Comment: @JohnDibling : I fully agree, but the question was not about good design, but whether it's possible (or at least that's how I understood it).

Comment: Not sure why the downvote? Thanks for showing how it would be done. I agree that it's messy

Comment: @SanderDeDycker:  The question may not have been specifically about good or bad design, but that's irrelevant.  You have taught a newbie a poor hack around a non-existent problem and implied (by omission) that there is nothing wrong with this design.  Now PaulK or other future readers are going to go forward writing terrible code not considering the negative ramifications of what they are doing.  Very short-sighted.  By the way, I did not downvote you. I thought my criticism was enough.

Comment: In other words, *every* question asked on SO should be answered with good design in mind when answered by those with more experience than those asking the question.  How else will they learn?

Comment: @JohnDibling : fair enough - I can't assume that all readers of my answer will be able to make the correct judgement call for themselves, so I should have been more obvious about how bad of an idea this approach is (I'll fix that).

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  If I had downvoted you (I have not), I would at this point revert it.  If you go on to explain *why* this is bad practice, I might even upvote.

Answer (score 0):

There's only one way to be sure that no `operator=` will be called after `operator[]` (by overloading an `operator[] const` function), but that wouldn't work every time.

As there's no (easy) way to be able to know when an `operator[]` is being called with the `operator=` right after, I'd suggest you to follow the example of [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) by providing two different functions:

- [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at), which always return a reference to the object; if the object does not exists, it is created
- [`at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at), which returns a reference only if the object is already there, otherwise it throws an exception of type `std::out_of_range`

Comment: Actually, using proxies, it's very easy to catch `[]` followed by an assignment.  A more difficult problem is if you also need to handle things like `[key].nonConstFunction()`.

Comment: @JamesKanze, using *proxies* doesn't sound like an *easy* task for the OP.

Comment: It should be:-).  It's a pretty standard C++ technique.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Just have the `operator[]` return a proxy.  Something like
the following should work.  (I'm using `std::map` for the
implementation; you can map it to whatever you're using)

```
template <typename KeyType, typename MappedType>
class MyMap
{
    std::map<KeyType, MappedType> myImpl;
//  ...
public:
    void set( KeyType const& key, MappedType const& value )
    {
        myImpl[key] = value;
    }
    MappedType get( KeyType const& key )
    {
        auto entry = myImpl.find( key );
        if ( entry == myImpl.end() ) {
            throw DesiredException();
        }
        return entry->second;
    }

    class Proxy
    {
        MyMap* myOwner;
        Key myKey;
    publc:
        Proxy( MyMap& owner, Key const& key )
            : myOwner( &owner )
            , myKey( key )
        {
        }
        Proxy const& operator=( MappedType const& value ) const
        {
            myOwner->set( myKey, value );
            return *this;
        }
        operator MappedType() const
        {
            return myOwner->get( myKey );
        }
    };
    Proxy operator[]( KeyType const& key )
    {
        return Proxy( *this, key );
    }
    MappedType operator[]( KeyType const& key ) const
    {
        return get( key );
    }
};
```

I'm not sure that this is a good idea, however.  In general,
having a `get( KeyType )` which returns a pointer to the mapped
element, or a null pointer if it isn't present, seems more
natural in C++.